# Como coletar texto quando não tem classe HTML de referência - Crawler Python

Tags: python-3.x, web-crawler, web-scraping, scraping

Tenho a seguinte situação abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quero coletar "Texto para crawler" que está abaixo, como vou navegar até lá sem class ou id?

```
<td>Texto para crawler</td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a biblioteca [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) junto ao comando [`.find_all()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) para extrair todas as tags `td` de um site, sem especificar nenhuma `class`, `name` ou `id`, por exemplo.

**Código:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping'

html_page = requests.get(url)
html_source = html_page.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, 'html.parser')

td_tags = soup.find_all('td')

for td in td_tags:
    print(td, '\n')
```

**Output:**

```
<td class="mbox-image"><div style="width:52px"><img alt="Globe icon." data-file-height="290" data-file-width="350" height="40" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bd/Ambox_globe_content.svg/48px-Ambox_globe_content.svg.png" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bd/Ambox_globe_content.svg/73px-Ambox_globe_content.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bd/Ambox_globe_content.svg/97px-Ambox_globe_content.svg.png 2x" width="48"/></div></td> 

<td class="mbox-text"><span class="mbox-text-span">The examples and perspective in this article <b>deal primarily with the United States and do not represent a <a href="/wiki/Wikipedia:WikiProject_Countering_systemic_bias" title="Wikipedia:WikiProject Countering systemic bias">worldwide view</a> of the subject</b>. <span class="hide-when-compact">You may <a class="external text" href="//en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Web_scraping&amp;action=edit">improve this article</a>, discuss the issue on the <a href="/wiki/Talk:Web_scraping" title="Talk:Web scraping">talk page</a>, or <a href="/wiki/Wikipedia:Article_wizard" title="Wikipedia:Article wizard">create a new article</a>, as appropriate.</span> <small><i>(October 2015)</i></small> <small class="hide-when-compact"><i>(<a href="/wiki/Help:Maintenance_template_removal" title="Help:Maintenance template removal">Learn how and when to remove this template message</a>)</i></small></span></td>
```

Comment: Entendo, porém eu não vou conseguir salvar a informação que desejo no banco, pois acho que não é possível fazer uma expressão regular para identificar o texto ex: Pegar o texto do td que começa com "x" e termina com "z"

Comment: Explique melhor o que quer fazer... acho difícil "não ser possível"... é tudo uma questão de tratamento de dados. Você pode utilizar o método `.text` no `td` e unir filtros como `.startswith("x")` e `.endswith("z")`, para selecionar seu texto, ou até mesmo uma expressão regular bem definida, por exemplo.

Comment: Deu certo amigo, obrigado!